# Error while running Postgres container with docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

After running docker-compose up. I get the error below

> FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
> DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
> Waiting for db

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:

  redis:
    image: redis

  db:
    image: postgres:9.4
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER:postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD:postgres
       
  vote:
    image: voting-app
    ports:
    - 5000:80
         
  worker:
    image: worker-app
     
  result:
    image: result-app
    ports:
    - 5001:80
```

Answer (score 0):

I used postgres image version 12-alpine and it somehow worked

```
image: postgres:12-alpine
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_USER = postgres
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD = postgres
```